# A better way to wait for external js to complete before executing jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, external

I've got some jQuery code that requires 2 external .js to complete loading before I can successfully do what I need to do, and `$(document).ready` isn't working consistently enough; sometimes it works, other times it gets overwritten by the external .js code.

Is there some way to **ensure** that the page is completely done loading, including all external .js before my jQuery executes?

Comment: How are the 2 external js files included in the page?  Are they script tags in the head, or are they loaded with some other script method?

Comment: This is a WordPress site, they get loaded via a WordPress function, and the external .js code that I'm altering is from a plugin. I write my own jQuery code in a custom.js in my theme, called from the theme's functions.php.

Answer (score 9):

`$(document).ready` only waits for the DOM to be loaded. To wait until all resources in the page (including images, objects, scripts...) have been (down)loaded you can use `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function () {
  // do stuff
};
```

Additionally you should read: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: If any of his external js uses `window.onload` it's likely his problem will continue to persist (not likely, but still probable). To be safe, I'd avoid using `window.onload` for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible know what's a *better* way when we don't know anything about your project but, in general, it's good practice to do all your script loading right before the closing `</body>` tag. Then make sure you're jquery code is loaded after it's dependencies are.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <!-- your head stuff -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- your page markup here -->

    <!-- load scripts here -->
    <script src="library_with_no_dependencies.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="library_with_dependency_on_jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="your_js_code.js"></script>

    <script>
      // or you could embed your js here
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Just list them in the same order that you want them to load in. Using this method you don't need to use jquery's `$(document).ready` or `window.onload`, and your code will be executed much sooner than using either of those methods.

**You don't want to wait for *everything* to load, just the libraries that your javascript code is dependent on.**